# DDD Event Source raise event for created object

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I have Category class, that has children property. When creating category, I raise event CategoryCreated in constructor, which registers this event in BaseCategory. Also I have apply method in Category, that applies events to state.

```
 public class Category :BaseCategory
{
    public Category(string id, TranslatableString name, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        Raise(new CategoryCreated(id, name, timestamp));
    }
}
  public override void Apply(DomainEvent @event)
    {
        switch (@event)
        {
            case CategoryCreated e:
                 this.Id = e.Id;
                 this.Name = e.Name;
                 break;
                ...
```

Now suppose I want to create Category and add child to it.

```
var category = new Category("1","2",DateTime.UtcNow);
category.AddChild("some category", "name", DateTime.UtcNow);
foreach(var e in category.UncomittedEvents)
{  
    category.Apply(e);
}
```

When adding child I set private property ParentId of newly created category as parent's Id.

```
 public void AddChild(string id, string name,DateTime date)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));
        if (Children.Any(a => a.Id== Id))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Category already exist ");
        Raise(new CategoryAdded(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), this.Id/*parent id*/, name, DateTime.UtcNow));
    }


  public class CategoryAdded : DomainEvent
    {
        public CategoryAdded(string id, string parentId, string name, DateTime timestamp) {}
    }
```

The problem is, when applying events, parent id will be null because events were not applied yet and parent's Id property passed as parent id is null:

```
new CategoryAdded(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), this.Id /*parent id*/, name, DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Where is design mistake? 
Where and when should be CategoryCreated event raised? 
How would you tackle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is design mistake? Where and when should be CategoryCreated event raised? How would you tackle this situation?

OK, this is not your fault.  The literature *sucks*.

[CPearson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100596/54734) shows a common mechanism for fixing the symptoms, but I think it is important to see what is going on.

If we are applying the "event sourcing" pattern in its pure form, our *data model* would look like a stream of events:

```
class Category {
    private final List[Event] History;
}
```

Changes to the current state would be achieved by appending events to the History.

```
public Category(string id, TranslatableString name, DateTime timestamp) {
    History.Add(new CategoryCreated(id, name, timestamp));
}
```

And queries of the current state would be *methods* that would search through the event history looking for data.

```
public Id Id() {
    Id current = null;
    History.forEach( e -> {
        if (e instance of CreatedEvent) {
            current = CreatedEvent.Id(e)
        }
    });
    return current
}
```

The good news is that the design is relatively simple in principle.  The bad news is that the performance is dreadful - reading is usually much more common and writing, but every time we want to read something, we have to go skimming through the events to find the answer.

It's not always that bad -- properties that are constant for the entire life cycle of the entity will normally appear in the first event; to get the most recent version of a property you can often enumerate the history *backwards*, and stop on the first (most recent) match.

But it is still pretty awkward.  So to improve query performance we cache the interesting results in properties -- effectively using a snapshot to answer queries.  But for that to work, we need to update the cached values (the snapshot) when we add new events to the history.

So the Raise method should be doing two things, modifying the event history, and modifying the snapshot.  Modifying the event history is general purpose, so that work often gets shared into a common base class; but the snapshot is specific to the collection of query results we want to cache, so that bit is usually implemented within the "aggregate root" itself.

Because the snapshot when we restore the aggregate from the events stored in our database should match the live copy, this design often includes an Apply method that is used in both settings.

Comment: Perhaps I am misinterpreting what you are saying.  Are you not perhaps referring to a *projection*?  A projection would always be stored as the latest state.  The purpose of a *snapshot* would be a valid state that is stored for a specific aggregate version.  The snapshot is then retrieved and applied to the aggregate. 
 Only events after that snapshot version would be retrieved and applied to the aggregate.

Comment: I'm not convinced that "projection" is any better than "snapshot" - it is the same _pattern_ in both cases, but used in different contexts.  "Projection" risks the misunderstanding that people bring in the additional baggage of "read models", multiple streams, and eventual consistency, which isn't going to help.  "Record" might be a better term to use than both.

Comment: Interesting take on things.  The intent is slightly different though.  A projection is there solely for querying.  A snapshot is a heuristic to improve aggregate hydration.  In my own event sourcing mechanism I actually store a snapshot as a first-class event.  Do you subscribe to the idea that one should not query the domain model?  If so, how would you perform queries without projections?  It does seem from your answer that you would query the aggregate but that may be unwieldy for aggregate sets where a projection would be useful.  I'm no ES guru so alternate viewpoints are interesting :)

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Good point, I almost forgot that the only source of truth are events and model class is only cache to speed up process. Looking from this perspective makes things easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is design mistake?

Your Raise(...) method should also call Apply. Remember that your Aggregate is responsible for maintaining a consistent state. Applying events outside of your Aggregate violates that principle.

```
protected void Raise(DomainEvent @event)
{
    this.Apply(@event);
    this.UncomittedEvents.Add(@event);
}
```

Comment: Your answer with the accepted answer shows full picture: Events are source of truth and their cache should be maintained consistent. Thanks.